# Can't import TextInputDialog in a javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I have this code:

```
@FXML
private void addFilosoof(ActionEvent event) {
// naam van filosoof aan de gebruiker vragen
TextInputDialog dialog =new TextInputDialog();
dialog.setTitle("Text Input Dialog");
dialog.setHeaderText("Add philosopher");
dialog.setContentText("Enter name:");
dialog.showAndWait()
.ifPresent(response -> {
if (!response.isEmpty()){
// voeg nieuwe filosoof toe in model
domeinController.addFilosoof(response);
// zie volgende slide
listFilosofen.getSelectionModel().selectLast();
}
});
}
```

However if I copy paste it into netbeans, I should be getting the option to import TextInputDialog, but I'm not getting this option.

IS it possible that I need to use something else in Java8?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/) is no class `TextInputDialog`. But neither is [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/). So only you can know where that class comes from.

Comment: I needed to import http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs/1.0.2/

Comment: [`TextInputDialog`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/index.html?javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html) is included in the ea release of Java 8 update 40. If you are using that version, Netbeans should find the import.